# PHP - Count the values of an array not the keys?

Tags: php, arrays, count

In an array like this:

```
$array = array(
    'value1'=>'',
    'value2'=>'',
    'value3'=>'',
);
```

We can:

```
echo count($array);
// Outputs 3
```

But if we have an array like:

```
$array = array(
    'value1'=>'',
    'value2'=>'some value',
    'value3'=>'',
);
```

What is the best way to do the following?

```
echo someFunction($array);
// Outputs 1
```

Comment: What result do you expect for `[0, 'foo', '', null, false]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) in order to remove the empty values:

```
$array = array(
    'value1'=>'',
    'value2'=>'some value',
    'value3'=>'',
);
echo count(array_filter($array)); // prints 1
```

Answer (score 1):

loop over the array and test each element for truthy

Same as array_filter, but faster (and does not allocate another array, so less memory used)